# want to do mulitple element hide using ajax helper on getting response

Tags: ajax, cakephp

want to do multiple div elements hide  using ajax helper on getting response.but not using like this complete=>element.hide(div1),element.hide(div2),element.hide(div3),element.hide(div4)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to hide multiple elements after an ajax response, you'll need to set up some javascript to do this. It depends on the javascript library you're using, but basically, you'll set $options['complete'] to something like "doStuffAfterComplete()".

Then, create a javascript function, like you normally would with your js library of choice. Using jQuery? Then it would be something like:

```
function doStuffAfterComplete(data) {
  $('div.whatevs').hide();
}
```